# Kinetic.js masked image with slow performance on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm new to kinetic and I don't know about performance issues.

I made [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/scalvo/t6PJ5/), you just have to click on the black and white image and drag over it, then, a colored circle apears.

The performance in chrome, safari on an Ipad, and even Opera Mobile on an android phone is quite good. In firefox it starts ok, but if you move the mouse for a while it slows down and doesn't work properly. The firebug profiler doesn't help a lot... How could I debug this issue in a better way?

In the drawing function there's an inner method onMove to do the hard work. I believe here lies the performance problem but I don't know how to achieve the same effect in a better way.

Any ideas?

```js
function draw(images) {

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container : 'container',
        width : 1024,
        height : 483
    }), bn_layer = new Kinetic.Layer(), color_layer = new Kinetic.Layer(), circle_layer = new Kinetic.Layer(), bn = new Kinetic.Image({
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
        image : images.bn,
        width : 1024,
        heigth : 483
    }), tmp_circle = null, movable = false;
    bn_layer.add(bn);
    tmp_circle = addCircle(circle_layer, images);

    var onMove = function() {
        if (movable) {
            var pos = getMousePosition(stage);
            circle_layer.draw();
            tmp_circle.remove();

            tmp_circle.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y)
            tmp_circle.setFillPatternImage(images.color);
            tmp_circle.setFillPatternOffset(pos.x, pos.y);
            circle_layer.add(tmp_circle);
        }
    }
    stage.on("mousemove touchmove", onMove);

    stage.on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
        debug("activo")
        circle_layer.show();
        movable = true;
        onMove();
        circle_layer.draw();
    });

    stage.on("mouseup touchend", function() {
        debug("inactivo")
        circle_layer.draw();
        tmp_circle.remove();
        circle_layer.hide();
        movable = false;
    })
    //stage.add(color_layer);
    stage.add(bn_layer);

    stage.add(circle_layer);
    circle_layer.hide();
}
```

**Update**: Changing the mouse event for a requestAnimationFrame  method controlled with a flag the performance improves a lot in firefox on windows. In firefox on Linux the performance is still crappy.

I think this might have some relation with what is commented in this topic:
[Poor Canvas2D performance with Firefox on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486910/poor-canvas2d-performance-with-firefox-on-linux)

There they are talking about a possible bug in firefox related to the cairo libraries:
http://blog.mozilla.org/joe/2011/04/26/introducing-the-azure-project/
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781731

**Updated code**

```
function Anim(layer, funcion){
        var run = false;
        var callback = funcion;
        this.layer = layer;

        function animate(){
            callback();
            if (!run){
                return;
            }
            requestAnimFrame(function(){
                animate();
            })
        };
        this.start = function(){
            run = true;
            animate();
        };
        this.stop = function(){
            run = false;
        };
    }

    //draw on frames
    function drawAnim(images){
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container : 'container',
            width : 1024,
            height : 483
        }), bn_layer = new Kinetic.Layer(), 
        hitareas_layer = new Kinetic.Layer(), 
        circle_layer = new Kinetic.Layer(), 
        bn = createImage(images.bn), 
        tmp_circle = null, 
        movable = false, 
        hit_areas = null, 
        c = 0,
        colorArea = function() {
            if (movable) {

                var pos = getMousePosition(stage);
                debug("posicion: "+pos.x+" "+pos.y+" " +c+ " " +tmp_circle.getX()+ " "+tmp_circle.getY());
                if(pos.x !== tmp_circle.getX() || pos.y !== tmp_circle.getY()){
                    c++;
                    circle_layer.draw();
                    tmp_circle.remove();

                    tmp_circle.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
                    tmp_circle.setFillPatternImage(images.color);
                    tmp_circle.setFillPatternOffset(pos.x, pos.y);
                    circle_layer.add(tmp_circle);
                }


            }
        },
        anim = new Anim(null, function(){
            colorArea();
        }),
        onPress = function() {
            circle_layer.show();
            //hitareas_layer.hide()
            movable = true;
            colorArea();
            circle_layer.draw();
            anim.start();
        }, onRelease = function() {
            anim.stop();
            circle_layer.draw();
            tmp_circle.remove();
            circle_layer.hide();
            //hitareas_layer.show()
            movable = false;
            c=0;
        };
        //hit_areas = setHitAreas(bn_layer);
        bn_layer.add(bn);
        tmp_circle = addCircle(100, {
            x : 50,
            y : 50
        });
        hit_areas = setHitAreas(hitareas_layer, images.color);
        bn_layer.on(HitArea.HITTED, function(){
            console.log("this");
        })
        //descomentar si queremos efecto al mover el rat�n
        //stage.on("mousemove touchmove", colorArea);
        stage.on("mousedown touchstart", onPress);
        stage.on("mouseup touchend", onRelease);

        stage.add(bn_layer);

        stage.add(circle_layer);
        stage.add(hitareas_layer);
        circle_layer.hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `if (movable)` condition outside of `onMove()` function, this way you`ll not check every time for this capability:

```
if (movable) {
          var onMove = function() {
            var pos = getMousePosition(stage);
            circle_layer.draw();
            tmp_circle.remove();
            tmp_circle.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y)
            tmp_circle.setFillPatternImage(images.color);
            tmp_circle.setFillPatternOffset(pos.x, pos.y);
            circle_layer.add(tmp_circle);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. It's just a boolean value. It is set true on the "mousedown" or "touchdown" event. The function onMove is the one repeated, the function draw is only executed when the dom is loaded. If I placed it outside the function I would be repeating processes even though the user is not pressing on the image.